# android edit text how to start typing at the top left?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have this `EditText`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lines="5"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="@string/app_name" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My problem is that typing starts at the middle of the EditText.

**My question is how to start typing at the top left of the EditText?**

Comment: you have to android:gravity="top|left"

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try `android:gravity="top"`
so your code will be :

```
<EditText
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:gravity="top"
     android:inputType="textMultiLine"
     android:lines="5"
     android:singleLine="false"
     android:text="@string/app_name" />
```

Answer (score 5):

I think it should work.

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:lines="5"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:gravity="top|left"
    android:text="@string/app_name" />
```

Answer (score 0):

`top|left` will work, but for right-to-left locales `android:gravity="top|start"` is better.

Snippet of description of warning in IDE:

> Using Gravity#LEFT and Gravity#RIGHT can lead to problems when a
>   layout is rendered in locales where text flows from right to left. Use
>   Gravity#START and Gravity#END instead. Similarly, in XML gravity and
>   layout_gravity attributes, use start rather than left.